# How to using httpGet in esp32 from webAPI local Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, local, esp32

I am using TinyGSM and ArduinoHttpClient libraries for http Get on server local Asp.net.
For available APIs e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1, my source code works fine, but for asp.net's local API ,it doesn't work. My code:

```
const char server[]   = "localhost:28212";
const char resource[] = "/api/Led";
const int  port       = 443;
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
TinyGsm        modem(SerialAT);
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
HttpClient          http(client, server, port);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  GSM_Init();
  TinyGsmAutoBaud(SerialAT, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX);
  delay(6000);
  Serial.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
}
void loop() {
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
  Serial.print(apn);
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
    Serial.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  Serial.print(" success");

  if (modem.isGprsConnected()) {
    Serial.println("GPRS connected");
  }
  Serial.print(F("Performing HTTPS GET request... "));
  http.connectionKeepAlive();  // Currently, this is needed for HTTPS
  int err = http.get(resource);
  if (err != 0) {
    Serial.println(F("failed to connect"));
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  int status = http.responseStatusCode();
  Serial.print(F("Response status code: "));
  Serial.println(status);
}
```

Comment: how do you want to reach your local server from Internet? but first 'locahost' is the name for the device to refer to itself.

Comment: I run IIS express Asp.net server. The server path I get is https://localhost:44341/api/Led

Comment: on the PC the localhost is the PC and on the esp8266 the localhost is the esp8266. note the word 'local'

Comment: So how should I call it? Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: how would you access it from a different device (other computer, phone, tablet)?